# PHP Sync over ftp giving errors

Tags: php, ftp, synchronization

So I got this code that's suppose to grab all the contents from /upload/ folder on remote host and copy it into the location where the file is at. Code looks like this:

```
<?php 
$ftp_server = "server"; 
$conn_id = ftp_connect ($ftp_server) 
    or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "user", "password"); 
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) 
    die("FTP Connection Failed"); 

ftp_sync ("/update/"); 

ftp_close($conn_id);  

function ftp_sync ($dir) { 

    global $conn_id; 

    if ($dir != ".") { 
        if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, $dir) == false) { 
            echo ("Change Dir Failed: $dir<BR>\r\n"); 
            return; 
        } 
        if (!(is_dir($dir))) 
            mkdir($dir); 
        chdir ($dir); 
    } 

    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "."); 
    foreach ($contents as $file) { 

        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') 
            continue; 

        if (@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $file)) { 
            ftp_chdir ($conn_id, ".."); 
            ftp_sync ($file); 
        } 
        else 
            ftp_get($conn_id, $file, $file, FTP_BINARY); 
    } 

    ftp_chdir ($conn_id, ".."); 
    chdir (".."); 

} 
?>
```

When I run it in an empty folder it does what it's suppose to. However, if I run it in a folder that contains the files from /update/ it will give me two errors. The errors are listed below

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in /home/limited/public_html/download.php on line 25

Warning: chdir() [function.chdir]: No such file or directory (errno 2) in /home/limited/public_html/download.php on line 26
```

It's suppose to just overwrite the files with new ones, not throw errors.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Either the script (actually the user running the script) has no permissions to create new folders on the server **OR** the folder where you are trying to copy the files and create new folders is restricted from your user.

Try with a user that has higher permissions or add write permissions to the folder where you want to sync the files into

Comment: Well I ran this script as anyone from "url.com/download.php" and tried it there. So if I wanted to run it like that, I'd have to be logged in  to the website itself with user that has permissions? :o